# Windows 10/11 disable WiFi for Users group

Tags: windows-10, networking, user-accounts, uac, wifi-configuration

I would like to disable WiFi access for all user accounts on a specific laptop. Is there a way to do it via the OS? I would like administrators to still be able to use WiFi while users can only use wired internet.

I hope some one can help me out... As my next choice of solution is to just remove the WiFi card... Which I'd rather not do...

Comment: Not as far as I know. What you want can be done in some (probably most) wireless router setups.

Comment: See if this Microsoft article helps you.   ......    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1164385/internet-blocking-in-gpo-for-a-specific-user  ....  This uses the idea of a proxy server to block some users.

Comment: The problem is I do not want to block internet. Just specifically WiFi. I want this laptop to use local network instead of WiFi hotspot shared from a phone. Local network has firewall restrictions that are easily bypassed by just sharing internet from the users phone...

Comment: I do not think you can block some connections for some users. No way to do that so far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Ethernet and Wireless are just two different forms of TCP/IP networking.  So from the point of view of Windows, you cannot have a user able to use Ethernet and not Wireless.

Also the laptop may find itself in a cafe or like spot and need wireless access.  Removing the wireless card does not work in this environment. As a brute force method, removing the wireless card can be used.

What can work is to match the laptop to its working environment. Ensure there is only on Wireless Access Point or Router in this environment.

Now make a Wireless AP Profile with a secure password only known to the administrator.  Now the Admin has wireless access and the other users do not.

This is probably as close as you will get.

Comment: Yes they are a form of TCP/IP but they are on different hardware components. Logically it should be possible to allow access to an ethernet port but not the WiFi card as they are separate physical hardware. But hey there are plenty of illogical things on windows... Regarding access point control if you take into consideration that every user can have a phone and easily share their mobile internet with a WiFi hotspot it is impossible to ensure that there is only 1 WiFi access point. That or you need a secure facility with guards to search every one going in and out...

Comment: n Windows itself you can’t control not using the wireless NIC not to be used by just user name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but ethernet adapters are a completely separate layer of the network stack from any protocols, and can operate any protocol, not just TCP/IP.  They can be controlled independently of each other as well as other layers in the stack. Obviously if all available adapters are disabled, the network won't work.

To address your question, it will depend on a number of factors including the technical level of the users and the configuration of the computer and network. Without knowing everything about the setup and environment, its hard to say for sure, but it is possible to accomplish what you want.

A basic option might be to create a couple of shell scripts setup to run at login (startup). Non-admin user accounts would run a script containing something like

```
netsh interface set interface [Wireless Adapter Name] disable
```

and the opposite (enable) could be run for Admin accounts. This depends on the Windows permission to be able to enable and disable the adapters, which could be a sticking point for you or not. If the adapter is disabled, they cannot connect to ANY wireless networks, only wired.

If this is in a corporate environment, you might be able to accomplish the same functions using login scripts, or by executing the same commands/scripts mentioned above by using Group Policy.

Hopefully that steers you in the right direction if you're still trying to accomplish your original objective.

Answer (score 0):

An even better option is to use group policy.

Configure a wireless profile that only allows connection to certain SSID's - and leave the list blank. The user will be able to use Ethernet no problem, and they will be able to view a list of Wireless connections, but they will not be able to connect.

Then if you need to, you can allow a subset of your users to connect to a certain list of SSID's.